# Add The Great Outdoors to migration targets for off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, migration

Would it make sense to add [Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) to the available migration targets for off-topic questions?

<sup>This is not a duplicate of the other question, adding useless blabla to fool the system.</sup>

Comment: @gerrit Ach good catch.